# Sending request to "/login" via Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

Here is my login template for sending post request to my SpringBoot application, with JAVA backend:

```
<template>
    <div div="login">
        <div class="login-form">
            <b-card
                    title="Login"
                    tag="article"
                    style="max-width: 20rem;"
                    class="mb-2"
            >
                <div>
                    <b-alert
                            :show="dismissCountDown"
                            dismissible
                            variant="danger"
                            @dismissed="dismissCountDown=0"
                            @dismiss-count-down="countDownChanged"
                    > {{ alertMessage }}
                    </b-alert>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <b-form-input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="username" v-model="username"/>
                    <div class="mt-2"></div>

                    <b-form-input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" v-model="password"/>
                    <div class="mt-2"></div>
                </div>

                <b-button v-on:click="login()" variant="primary">Login</b-button>

                <hr class="my-4"/>

                <b-button variant="link">Restore your password</b-button>
            </b-card>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import {AXIOS} from './http-common'

    export default {
        name: 'SignIn',
        data() {
            return {
                username: '',
                password: '',
                dismissSecs: 5,
                dismissCountDown: 0,
                alertMessage: 'Request error'
            }
        },
        methods: {
            login() {
                AXIOS.post(`/login`, this.$data.username, this.$data.password)
                    .then(response => {
                        this.$store.dispatch('login', {
                            'roles': response.data.authorities,
                            'username': response.data.username
                        });
                        this.$router.push('/today')
                    }, error => {
                        this.$data.alertMessage = (error.response.data.message.length < 150) ? error.response.data.message : 'Request error. Please, report this error website owners';
                        console.log(error);
                        this.showAlert();
                    })
                    .catch(e => {
                        console.log(e);
                        this.showAlert();
                    })
            },
            countDownChanged(dismissCountDown) {
                this.dismissCountDown = dismissCountDown
            },
            showAlert() {
                this.dismissCountDown = this.dismissSecs
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

But, if I send my post request to "/login" url - I will get an error on my backend part, that the "username" field is not presented. This "username" field should be as text, not as an object. Where is an error in my code? Thaks!

Comment: Have you tried to use something like `AXIOS.post(`/login`, { username: this.username, password: this.password });`?  Note that I assume that your application will accept two parameters called `username` and `password`.

Answer (score 1):

I am going to assume that your back-end requires a POST body that is similar to this:

```
{
  "username": "myUsername",
  "password": "myPassword"
}
```

If this is true, then this is the line of code that is causing your problem:

```
AXIOS.post('/login', this.$data.username, this.$data.password)
```

You just need to change it to this instead:

```
AXIOS.post(`/login`, { username: this.$data.username, password: this.$data.password })
```